# ajaxStop not on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a program that, given an array of youtube video ids, calls the Youtube API and returns data about said videos.  I do this by calling:

```
$.getScript("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+encodeURIComponent(id)+"?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=youtubeFeedCallback");
```

This is done for each video id in the array.  Is there a way to use ajaxStop to then do something (in my case modifying the DOM) once all of these requests finish?  I am not doing this on any sort of .click or .mouseover or other such event, these requests are simply sent out when the page is loaded.  I tried to do:

```
$.ajaxStop(function () { (do something here) });
```

But I got the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'ajaxStop'.  Also will this work if some of the requests return 403 Forbiddens?

Edit: SOLVED

Fixed it, although my solution is a bit hacky.  Instead of using $.getScript I instead just used the $.ajax function.  I then had a global counter variable, and using the "error" method of $.ajax, incremented the count on error or on success.  Then I just called what I wanted to when the count variable was equal to the length of my array.  Id still love to hear if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ajaxComplete event. There is a jQuery method for it. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

You may need to count the amount of requests so you know when all of them are complete.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, when link it with div block.

Example:

```
$("#smthing").ajaxComplete(function (){do smth})
```